# Can someone tells me what is the error mean from Eclipse debug?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse, jdbc

I've just learnt to walk through my code through Eclipse debugger.
However, I do not know why the process kept going back to line 71 - `ps.executeUpdate()` whereas the console mentioned the error at line 79 and it also mentioned other error lines at other classes.  Hope someone can tell me what's going on.

Here's the code on subjectDAOImpl:

```
public void insertSubject(subject s) throws MyDataException { 
    try {       
        openConnection();               
        String qry = INSERT_QRY1; 
        //"INSERT INTO hi5project.subject(subject)VALUES (?)";              
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(qry);
        int i = 0;            
        String[] sub = new String[3];

        while(i < sub.length){              
            String e = s.getSubj(); 
            ps.setString(1, e); 
            ps.executeUpdate();        - line 71
        }

        if (ps !=null )
            closeConnection();

       }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new MyDataException("DB Error"); - line79
       }
   }
```

**Controller:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    subject m = new subject();
    manager mgr = new manager();
    try {
        String[] sub = request.getParameterValues("subject");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < sub.length) {
            sub[i] = m.getSubj();
            mgr.insertSubject(m);
            out.println("Successful registered subject");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: please show both the error as well as the code as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: i suspect in the way that you executing the prepared statement inside a loop, i think this can cause a problem

Comment: @YCF_L, could you be more clear about the problem?  Should I put the String[]sub outside the try ? or ...Sori..but I am not clear..

Comment: check my answer @KarenGoh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you are executing multiple statement i would suggest to use Statement Batching instead

I don't know why you are using :

```
String[] sub = request.getParameterValues("subject");
int i = 0;
while (i < sub.length) {
    sub[i] = m.getSubj();
    mgr.insertSubject(m);
    out.println("Successful registered subject");
}
```

I think you need just to use :

```
String[] sub = request.getParameterValues("subject");
mgr.insertSubject(m);
out.println("Successful registered subject");
```

and you can change the signature of insertSubject to `insertSubject(String[] sub)`, now you can use this batch to insert the data:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
try (PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(qry)) {

    for (String s : sub) {//loop throw your array
        insert.setString(1, s);
        insert.addBatch();
    }
    insert.executeBatch();//executing the batch 
}
connection.commit();//commit statements to apply changes
```

---

**Note** your loop can not be finish because you don't increment the `i`, i already change a little of your logic hope this can help you, another thing it seems that the sub array always empty so you always use `null`

Comment: My controller I need to read the values from my HTML form. So, I'd still need to getParameterValues....

Comment: what did you mean @KarenGoh ?

Comment: I thought you are showing the correct code for my controller then I realised that it is for the other class.  By the way, you need not closeConnection() after connection.commit() ? and do I  have to add in the catch Exception ?

Comment: @KarenGoh this piece of code you have to use in the place of `while(i < sub.length){              
            String e = s.getSubj(); 
            ps.setString(1, e); 
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }`

Comment: Yes.  I understand now.  But, how to add closeConnection() and the catch Exception to your code?  I tried but it is not working

Comment: @KarenGoh check my edit, note, are you sure that you are using an empty array read the note in comment it seams that you insert just null values are you sure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146329/discussion-between-karen-goh-and-ycf-l).